# PMOS as a switch

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to get a PMOS(BS250) act as a switch according to following diagrams.
[image]

But the motor(its a servo) doesn't work no matter what signal I give at the gate. Any inputs on why this might be happening?

As gar as I understand, MOSFET works as a switch when it is in linear region. When I give 3.3 V at the gate, Vsd < Vsg - |Vth| should be satisfied, and it should work.

Any inputs are really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What is source , is it PWM from uC ( which controller is this which give 40 mA sink current) , also what is motor spec , what type of control spec motor need to run.

Comment: I am getting the PWM from Erle Brain 2, and I am trying to drive a servo.

Comment: Why not just use an AND gate here intead of messing around with MOSFETs and resistors?

Comment: Vth is the voltage that just _starts_ to turn the FET on. You need more to get 40mA. But if you make the load resistance higher then the FET won't have to switch as much current. A 100 Ohm resistor requires 40mA to get 4V. Is there some reason you have to have such a low resistance?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to drive it from the source? Have you tryied to put the PWM signal into the gate and the source to Vdd? This would work, but you have to ensure at least 40 mA flowing from the power supply to the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply '3.3v' to the gate, the source-gate voltage is ... what?
Is Vs = 5V?   Then '3.3v' makes the Vgs = -1.7V (which probably isn't
enough to turn on the PMOS).   BS250 is rated for switching
at Vgs = -10V.

Answer (score 0):

The question is, what exactly do you expect from a servo, or actually, what is that "servo motor" you have. If it's a complete drive, i suspect you are trying to turn it on with "enable" input, which is far from being enough to move. If this is just a DC brushless motor, than it's not enough to move it either.

In any case, most common is to use N-channel MOSFET or NPN for this specific application.